# cambiar estatus de abierto a cerrado

Tags: php

hola a todos quisiera ver si existe una forma de que cambie un estado de una encuesta al momento de que el usuario la conteste.

es decir yo tengo un calendario de tareas, aquí agrego nuevas tareas y se ven en una lista. también tengo la opción de Realizar. y lo que requiero es que el usuario de clic aquí y al momento de contestar la encuesta cambie a contestado. y solo hasta que el usuario la conteste y no al dar clic en Realizar.

no se si me puedan ayudar con algún ejemplo.

```html
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
//llamamo al archivo de sesion.php
include 'header.php';
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!-- 
.estilo1 { 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 12px; 
color: #003366; 
} 
.estilo2 { 
color: #990000; 
font-weight: bold; 
} 
.estilo3 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #660099; } 
--> 
</style>
<section id="form">
    <form class="contact_form" action="GuardarTarea.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Calendario de Tareas</h2>
            </li>
            <table>
                <tr><td><label for="nombre">Fecha Deseada:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="deseada" step="1" min="2013-01-01" max="2099-12-31" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="nombre">Fecha de Limite:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="limite" step="1" min="2013-01-01" max="2099-12-31" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><label for="sel1">Quien Realizara la Auditoria?:</label></td>
                     <td><select name="auditor" id="auditor">
                     <option value="0">elige una opción</option>
                      <?php
                      $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY id");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                         echo '<option value="'.$valores[Nombre].'">'.$valores[Nombre].'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                       </select></td></tr>
                 <tr><td><label for="nombre">Que Auditoria se Realizara?:</label></td>
                     <td><select name="auditoria" id="auditoria">
                     <option value="0">elige una opción</option>
                      <?php
                      $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT * FROM encuestas ORDER BY id");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                         echo '<option value="'.$valores[titulo].'">'.$valores[titulo].'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                       </select></td></tr>
                 <td><input type="submit" name="opcion" class="submit" value="Guardar"></input></td>
            </table> </br>
 
            <?php
/* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$sql="select * from tareas";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");
 
/* Desplegamos cada uno de los registros dentro de una tabla */  
echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3>";
 
/*Priemro los encabezados*/
 echo "<tr>
         <th colspan=16 BGCOLOR='#BCC1C2' WIDTH='10%' face='Georgia' align='center'> Auditorias Programadas </th>
       <tr BGCOLOR='#DADDDE'>
         <th class='estilo1'> ID </th><th class='estilo1'> Auditor </th><th class='estilo1'> Auditoria </th>
         <th class='estilo1'> Fecha Deseada </th><th class='estilo1'> Fecha limite </th><th class='estilo1'> Estado </th><th class='estilo1'> Realizar </th>
      </tr>";
 
/*Y ahora todos los registros */
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<tr>
         <td align='right' class='estilo1'> $row[ID] </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $row[Auditor] </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $row[Auditoria] </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $row[Fdeseada] </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $row[Flimite] </td>
             <td class='estilo1'> $row[Estado] </td>
                 <td class='estilo1'><A HREF='verEncuesta.php'> Realizar </A></td>
 
      </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
 
?>
            
</section>
```

Comment: Me imagino que guardas el estado al momento que el usuario contesta la encuesta.  Si es asi, solo tendrias que chequear el valor de 'Estado' cuando despliegas la lista y cambiar lo que quieres que el usuario vea dependiendo de ese valor.

Comment: Puedes usar un evento `onChange` para cuando se modiquen los datos se dispare